# (postgresql)Столбец не существует

Tags: python, postgresql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Если через cmd выполняю:
`insert into medical_cards values(511111, 2, '-', 'д', 'н');`
то все ок, но при использовании "" вместо '', то возникает ошибка, что столбец не существует. Из-за этого код python не работает

```
def insert_medical_cards_table(medical_card_id, blood_type, rhesus_factor, allergy, chronic_diseases):
conn, cur = connect("vaccinatedDB", "postgres", "toor", "localhost", "5432")

try:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO medical_cards VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
               (medical_card_id, blood_type, rhesus_factor, allergy, chronic_diseases))

    conn.commit()

except Exception as error:
    print("error insert data into medical cards")
finally:
    if conn is not None:
        conn.close()

def create_medical_cards_table():
conn, cur = connect("vaccinatedDB", "postgres", "toor", "localhost", "5432")

try:
    command = """
        CREATE TABLE medical_cards(
            medical_card_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            blood_type INTEGER,
            rhesus_factor VARCHAR(1),
            allergy VARCHAR(1),
            chronic_diseases VARCHAR(1)
        ) 
    """

    cur.execute(command)
    conn.commit()

except Exception as error:
    print("error create users_medical_card_table")
finally:
    if conn is not None:
        conn.close()
```

Точно такой же код для другой таблицы работает

```
def insert_users_passport_data_table(passport_id, series, number, registration, date_birth, gender):
conn, cur = connect("vaccinatedDB", "postgres", "toor", "localhost", "5432")

try:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO passport_data VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
               (passport_id, series, number, registration, date_birth, gender))

    conn.commit()

except Exception as error:
    print("error insert data into passport data")
finally:
    if conn is not None:
        conn.close()
```

Comment: Ничего непонятно. В `Python` вы можете использовать любой вид кавычек. Покажите ваш код на питоне.

Comment: Добавьте этот код в сам вопрос, вы можете редактировать вопрос.

Comment: @CrazyElf причем я через python создаю 5 таблиц и пытаюсь добавить данные, но такая проблема возникает с 2-мя. Код создания и insert'а одинаков для всех

Comment: Но в преамбуле вопроса вы вставляете данные в одну таблицу, а в питоновском коде - в другую, поэтому непонятно, что вы между собой сравниваете в плане поведения, если это разные таблицы. Добавьте хотя бы саму ошибку (полностью текст!) и напишите, в какой строке кода питона она возникает.

Comment: @CrazyElf поменял код.

Comment: Так, ну вы ведь вообще не перечисляете столбцы, у вас в `INSERT` нет перечня столбцов, есть только значения. Так что покажите ошибку - не может оно ругаться, что нет столбца, ведь вы и не указали названия столбцов, наверняка ошибка другая какая-то.

Comment: @CrazyElf добавил скрин. Точно такой же код работает для 3 таблиц, единственное что там отличается это названия столбцов

Comment: Использование одинарных кавычек и двойных кавычек в Postgresql имеет разное синтаксическое значение. Одинарные обозначают строку, а двойные делают идентификаторы регистрозависимыми и позволяют включать пробелы в идентификатор, поэтому код с использованием двойных кавычек не работает в cmd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO medical_cards VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
               (medical_card_id, blood_type, rhesus_factor, allergy, chronic_diseases))
```

Насколько я понял, у вас тут пропущена запятая, должно быть так:

```
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO medical_cards VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", # вот здесь!!!
               (medical_card_id, blood_type, rhesus_factor, allergy, chronic_diseases))
```

На скрине у вас питон ругается, что вы к строке обращаетесь как к функции, у вас тут получается что-то типа `"строка"(параметры)` из-за того, что пропущена запятая.

Comment: поверить не могу что все из-за , я все сверял, где что не так написал. Спасибо

Comment: @user436750 Питон коварен в каких-то вещах, не всегда понятно, из-за чего ошибка. Но если б вы сразу текст ошибки показали, быстрей бы удалось докопаться в чём дело )